# What am I supposed to do in processContentChanges:?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsnotifications

This is my app's processContentChanges: method, which is triggered by `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification`:

```
- (void)processContentChanges:(NSNotification *)notification {    
    [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        // Merge incoming data updates in the managed object context
        [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

        // Post notification to trigger UI updates
#warning What do I actually do here?
    }];
}
```

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController`s throughout my app so that the UI updates automatically when changes are received from another device through iCloud. This all seems to work, but the comment saying `// Post notification to trigger UI updates` was there in the template method already. Am I actually supposed to do something here, or can I safely leave things the way they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although I haven't had confirmation of this I don't think there is anything else that needs to be done in this method as long as the following criteria are met:

1. You implement `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` correctly as per the template so that new content is merged to the managed object context
2. Your content is generated using `NSFetchedResultsController` objects
3. Your viewControllers conforms to the the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol, and implements `controllerWillChangeContent:`, `controllerDidChangeContent:` and `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath`
4. In those methods, update your views accordingly to display new content, remove deleted content, and update changed content.

If you have any objects which utilise CoreData without an `NSFetchedResultsController` then you might need to update these by manually re-fetching the data when `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` is posted by CoreData.